# is there a way to choose which parent width:100% should relate to in css

Tags: css

This questions can be rewritten as: choose what percentage refers to in css?

In css when i write width 100%. The hundred percent refers to the immediate parent whose width is copied. However, to get some effect I am trying to create, clipping effect, which is to compensate for lack of clipping features in css.

There are three divs. 1 > 2 > 3. One inside each other. I want div 3 to be wide as div 1. and div 3 is absolutely positioned. To align with div 1.

Div 2 will move right, thus clipping div 3. Overflow is hidden on div 2.

Div 1 has width 100%.

So how can i tell div 1 to extend to maximum width available AND div 3 to resize to div 1's width too.

I don't want to use javascript for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/brrvrepf/

HTML:

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C">
            <p>BBBB</p>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.A {
    height: 180px;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: 0;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.B {
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 180px;
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 170px;
}
.B, .C {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; top: 0; left:0;
}
.C {

    background-color: #f53f39;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide everything you've done thus far in a JSFiddle?

Comment: changing the width of B is affecting c. It's a valid behavior but not what i want. I want parent to clip child element while that child element keeps it's width related to parent's parent.

Comment: May I ask why?  What is your targeted behavior for this, besides just making width of div3 = width of div1?

Comment: clipping... for div 3

Comment: If you want Div1 and Div3 to be the same widths then they cannot be absolute positioned. Which means you would need to float Div2. Overall tho i'm not sure why anyone would need a set up like this, based on what i think you're asking this doesn't seem like good design.

Comment: Can you provide some solution

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the updated working code without JavaScript.**

HTML:

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C">
            <p>BBBB</p>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.A {
    height: 180px;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: 0;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.B {
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 180px;
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 170px;
    background-color: green;
}
.B, .C {
    width: 400px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
.C {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
    width: 100%
}
.C p{
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Here all the div's is defined by a color.

1. class/div A = Red
2. class/div B = Green
3. class/div C = Blue

Now if you will increase the width of "div A", "div C" width will automatically increase because of 100% width

Comment: JSFiddle Link: [**Click Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/zcgxamde/1/)